# Porto Theme 2.1.0 in Magento 2.1.1 Minicart Problem

Tags: magento2.1.0

After I upgrade my magento 2.0.7 in magento 2.1.1 I was experiencing this problem in my site. The minicart also is not functioning well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep inside your **minicart.phtml** file below code,

keep **minicart.phtml** file inside your theme,

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
```

In 2.0.7 theme,

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
                <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
```

In new 2.1.1 theme change below code,

```
<a class="action showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
```

After apply changes,

please run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear broswer cache.

Comment: I tried your codes, and followed all your instructions it will work but the minicart is messed up.

Comment: You have to remove var folder, clear browser cache and run deploy command

Comment: Hello I tried what you've intructed to me. But still the minicart is the same wit the one I posted below. Thanks

Comment: In console error are removed or still display, Have you clear browswer cache and cookie?

Comment: Yes I did what you say. but sad to say the minicart is still messed up.

Comment: Just like the picture I attached below this messages

Comment: In console knockout.js has always error